# Can I avoid doing this Row by Row

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, entity-framework

If I have two tables with columns as shown below.  I want to fill in the `ActualStart` and `ActualEnd` times based on the earliest and latest times scanned within that shift.

Is there a way to do this in linq or a set based way to do this in sql?

Currently I intend to use a cursor and go through each row in UsersShifts to get the earliest and latest fingerprint scan times within that user's shift and update it into `ActualStart` and `ActualEnd` columns

**UsersShifts**

- UsersShiftsId
- UserId
- ShiftStart
- ShiftEnd
- ActualStart
- ActualEnd

**FingerprintScan**

- UserId
- ScannedTime

Comment: I think you should provide some sample data and what the results that you want.  Otherwise, your question is rather vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in SQL by just adding the time constraint to your `JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    us.UsersShiftsId,
    us.UserId,
    us.ShiftStart,
    us.ShiftEnd,
    MIN(fs.ScannedTime) ActualStart,
    MAX(fs.ScannedTime) ActualEnd
FROM UsersShifts us
LEFT JOIN FingerprintScan fs
    ON us.UserId = fs.UserId
    AND fs.ScannedTime BETWEEN us.ShiftStart AND us.ShiftEnd 
GROUP BY
    us.UsersShiftsId,
    us.UserId,
    us.ShiftStart,
    us.ShiftEnd
```